# KeyError: 1720: Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, tflite

I'm following this tutorial on how to export my saved model to tflite for building an android app using my custom detection model [Link](https://medium.com/geekculture/build-android-app-for-custom-object-detection-tf-2-x-53904a08cfa2#fb5e)

But after executing this code

```
ObjectDetectorWriter = object_detector.MetadataWriter

_MODEL_PATH = "/content/detect.tflite"
_LABEL_FILE = "/content/labelmap.txt"
_SAVE_TO_PATH = "/content/tflite_with_metadata/detect.tflite"

writer = ObjectDetectorWriter.create_for_inference(
    writer_utils.load_file(_MODEL_PATH), [127.5], [127.5], [_LABEL_FILE])
writer_utils.save_file(writer.populate(), _SAVE_TO_PATH)

# Verify the populated metadata and associated files.
displayer = metadata.MetadataDisplayer.with_model_file(_SAVE_TO_PATH)
print("Metadata populated:")
print(displayer.get_metadata_json())
print("Associated file(s) populated:")
print(displayer.get_packed_associated_file_list())

model_meta = _metadata_fb.ModelMetadataT()
model_meta.name = "SSD_Detector"
model_meta.description = (
    "Identify which of a known set of objects might be present and provide "
    "information about their positions within the given image or a video "
    "stream.")

# Creates input info.
input_meta = _metadata_fb.TensorMetadataT()
input_meta.name = "image"
input_meta.content = _metadata_fb.ContentT()
input_meta.content.contentProperties = _metadata_fb.ImagePropertiesT()
input_meta.content.contentProperties.colorSpace = (
...
```

it gave an error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-2e8ec3b1f9af> in <cell line: 7>()
      5 _SAVE_TO_PATH = "/content/tflite_with_metadata/detect.tflite"
      6 
----> 7 writer = ObjectDetectorWriter.create_for_inference(
      8     writer_utils.load_file(_MODEL_PATH), [127.5], [127.5], [_LABEL_FILE])
      9 writer_utils.save_file(writer.populate(), _SAVE_TO_PATH)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow_lite_support/metadata/python/metadata_writers/object_detector.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    210 
    211     # Output metadata according to output_tensor_indices.
--> 212     output_metadata = [indices_to_tensors[i] for i in output_tensor_indices]
    213 
    214     # Create subgraph info.

KeyError: 1720
```

here's my jupyter notebook [Link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10oPq2bKFR-hNzLC5rtTUS6JNyek5wMQJ?usp=drive_link)

I've tried other methods but all give the same error.

Comment: Your issue is that your indices_to_tensors list is not as long as your output_tensor_indices. While this is just a Python error, it does mean something is wrong with your model training flow.

Comment: @transposeglobal how do I fix it?

Comment: It depends on your input files. I see that this is a large flow and you are very deep into it with this step. I don't know everything about this flow, but I would recommend you trace back your steps and make sure you have followed the steps closely. If you do find a more specific problem with it, feel free to ask here.